# XML R How to retrieve values (could this be a namespace issue?)

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Just when I thought I understood XPath! I must be missing something really simple, but I can't select the value of the node "citedby-count" in the following:

```
xml <- "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <search-results xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:cto='http://www.elsevier.com/xml/cto/dtd' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:prism='http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/' xmlns:opensearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'>

            <entry>
                 <prism:url>http://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/111111</prism:url>
                 <dc:title>Paper Title</dc:title>
                 <citedby-count>1</citedby-count>
            </entry> 
        </search-results>"

doc <- xmlParse(xml)
```

I've tried

```
doc["//citedby-count"]
```

and

```
doc["//{'citedby-count'}"]
```

and

```
doc["//entry"]
```

but all return

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

however,

```
doc["//dc:title"]
```

works just fine.

Have I just been looking at this too long? Please help!

**Edit:**I thought this was because of the hyphen but it can't be because

```
doc["//entry"]
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: `doc["//atom:citedby-count", namespaces=c(atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]` (dealing with default namespaces in R and the XML-ish packages are a royal pain)

Comment: Aaahhh, thank you! I've been working with these documents for weeks and have never had a problem with namespaces. What is it about this document that makes atom the namespace for entry and citedby-count? I thought I sorta understood them but now I'm completely baffled

Comment: i just made a default namespace and called it `atom`. i cld have called it `fred` or `q`. The XML pkg will use that to name the default namespace and then you use that to reference the tags that have no `:` namespace associated with them.

Comment: Ok. That actual namespace is in the xml so I was confused. I find that in my code I can get the same result with doc["//atom:citedby-count"], is that because atom is already in the root node?

Comment: oh man. i didn't try that :-) I just assumed it was borking on the default namespace (and i didn't read the rest of them to see that `atom` was in there). `unlist(sapply(xmlNamespaces(doc), "[", "id"))` shows everything R read in. I don't think `citedby-count` is an actual Atom NS tag. This may be a "got lucky" instance.

Comment: Thanks, wow I just really don't understand namespaces. [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428744/example_file.xml) is an xml file I navigated every which way using XPath and I never referenced namespaces unless the node had a colon in the name. How is this file different? I'll keep trying to understand more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common namespace prefix is declared as `xmlns:foo="..."`, where `foo` is the prefix, and it is used in element name *explicitly* as `<foo:bar>` where `bar` is the element's local-name. Apart from that there is *default namespace*. It is namespace declared without prefix like `xmlns="..."`, and the usage is *implied* on the element where default prefix is declared *as well as* the descendant elements, unless something is overriding the default namespace inheritance i.e having local default namespace or using explicit prefix in the descendant element's name.

That's the first part the story, which is about namespace in XML. On the other hand, XPath has no idea about default namespace. In XPath, element without prefix is *always* considered in empty namespace. To bridge the difference between XML and XPath regarding default namespace, usually when you need to query element in default namespace, you have to define a prefix pointing to the XML's default namespace and use that prefix in the XPath expression. That's basically what [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) suggested in the first comment, something like the following (the prefix can be anything as long as it is mapped to the correct default namespace) :

```
doc["//d:citedby-count", namespaces=c(d="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
```

but turns out that your XML has an explicit prefix, `atom`, which already points to the same namespace uri and can be used directly.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand namespaces a bit more. But [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428744/example_file.xml) is a file I navigated extensively without ever explicitly referencing a namespace (unless the element did) and I never had a problem. What do you see a difference?

Comment: @SarahHailey Sure, XML in that link doesn't have any default namespace. All namespaces there are declared with prefix (`xmlns:some_prefix_here="..."` contrast with default namespace pattern `xmlns="..."`)

Comment: Thanks! Super useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `doc["//x:citedby-count", namespace = "x"]` to deal with default namespaces (it is from the examples of `xpathApply`).