# How to get xml attribute value in R

Tags: r, xml

Hej all,
I have load an XML-File into R and want to extract an attribute value.

```
<espa_metadata version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://espa.cr.usgs.gov/v2 http://espa.cr.usgs.gov/schema/espa_internal_metadata_v2_0.xsd">
<global_metadata></global_metadata>
<bands>
<band product="cfmask" source="toa_refl" name="cfmask" category="qa" data_type="UINT8" nlines="7801" nsamps="7651" fill_va.lue="255">
<percent_coverage>
<cover type="clear">40.35</cover>
<cover type="cloud">39.99</cover>
</percent_coverage>
</band>
</bands>
</espa_metadata>
```

I want to extract the value 39.99 for cover type="cloud". 
I used the following approach but I only get "NULL"

```
library(XML)
data <- xmlParse("LC82030342015346LGN00.xml")
xpathApply(data,"//percent_coverage/cover[@type='cloud']" , xmlValue)
```

Any ideas? Thank u in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce here! **39.99** does result. Check if you are pointing to correct document.

Comment: I did not have any problems extracting `39.99`. Are you sure `xmlParse` actually parsed the file (i.e., file name is correct and file is in working directory). Check the value for `data`.

Comment: I checked it and also with other files and I know that it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @aichao Yes I'm sure! The output for `data` is also correct

Comment: I usually discourage posting links to files on file sharing services, but there may be an issue with BOM or other encoding issues that were masked by the snippet paste into SO. Can you link to the raw file directly?

Comment: Here is the original file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1fah8iot5bnuaz/LC82030342015346LGN00.xml?dl=0

Comment: I'm not sure why, but treating it as HTML instead of XML makes it work: `library(xml2) ; xml %>% read_html() %>% xml_find_all('//cover[@type="cloud"]') %>% xml_double()`

Comment: @PiotrDe Your XML has *default namespace* declared at the root element : `xmlns="http://espa.cr.usgs.gov/v2"`.

Comment: Here are some similar questions I have encountered in the past which using `r` : [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954792/xpath-and-namespace-specification-for-xml-documents-with-an-explicit-default-nam/24955051#24955051), [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049887/xml-r-how-to-retrieve-values-could-this-be-a-namespace-issue/34313931#34313931)